# Cannot access nginx reverse proxy remotely

Tags: ssl, nginx, raspberry-pi, router, portforwarding

I am using nginx on a Raspberry Pi in my local network. The IP address is 192.168.188.32.
I am using a Fritz!Box as Router and a myfritz.net address as a DynDNS. Also, I enabled a port forwarding on the Router for the Pi and Port 80 on the Router and the Pi.

My nginx configuration:

```
server {
    listen                          80;
    server_name                     192.168.188.32;
    return 301                      https://$server_name$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen                          443 ssl;
    server_name                     192.168.188.32;
    ssl_certificate                 /etc/ssl/openhab.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key             /etc/ssl/openhab.key;

    location / {
            proxy_pass                            http://localhost:8080/;
            proxy_set_header Host                 $http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP            $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For      $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto    $scheme;
            satisfy                                 any;
            allow                                   192.168.0.1/24;
            allow                                   127.0.0.1;
            deny                                    all;
            auth_basic                              "Username and Password Required";
            auth_basic_user_file                    /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;
    }
}
```

Local access is possible but when I try to access remotely, I get redirected to the IP 192.168.188.32 and I get a timeout ("Safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding"). I tried to change the `server_name` to my `xxxxxxxxx.myfritz.net` but then I don't have local access anymore. Even if I opened more ports in the Router, it didn't work.

I hope you can help me :-)

Comment: You use `$server_name` but that should be `$host`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#var_host).

Comment: @RichardSmith you mean in both `server` sections or in the return 301?

Comment: Try: `return 301 https://$host$request_uri;`

Comment: Thanks for your help but it doesn't work